# Running time of Kruskal's algorithm by varying the sorting time

Tags: algorithm, graph, analysis, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

I was doing an analysis of minimum spanning trees and was wondering how the sorting time would effect the overall time complexity of Kruskal's algorithm?

Example:

1. If sorting can be done in `O(n log log n)`
2. If sorting can be done in `O(n)`

Would the answer still remain `O(e log n)` for both the cases or would it change?

Comment: you should specify what is n and what is e?

Comment: if you found the answer useful, please mark it as answer and vote it.

Comment: @Ahmad OP has only 11 rep, so he/she cannot upvote. But if you found the question interesting you may vote it as well ;-)

Comment: @ring0 Thank you, I've already done it. I needed some votes to my questions and answers to leave an unfair ban, if you also reviewed my questions and answers please consider them for voting.

Answer (score 1):

The time of Kruskal algorithm is  `O(e log e)` and its the time for sorting the edges. If you can do it in O(e), considering the rest of algorithm to find the minimum spanning tree is O (e log n), you have `O(e) + O(e log n)` . Since `e=O(n^2)` then the algorithm time would be `O(n^2 log n)` or `O(e log n)`. if sorting takes O(e log log e) with the same analysis the overall time would be `O(e log log e)`.

**Details**: The time for finding minimum spanning tree is calculated by the time you need for sorting edges and then a loop (e times) in which you remove each edge from the sorted list and examine if it connects two disjoint regions or not. (this check needs O (log n) ) and the time of the loop would be `O(e log n)` as mentioned above.

using more sophisticated disjoint-set data structure to find and check disjoint regions the loop has O(E α(V)) time, where α is the extremely slowly growing inverse of the single-valued Ackermann function ([WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm))

Answer (score 1):

If you use disjoint set for implementing kruskal algorithm complexity will be  `SortComplexity+Eα(E)`

(`E` is number of edges and `alpha` is very slowly growing function (according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) less than 5 for practial value of `n`))

So If sorting can be done in `O(n)` then the complexity of kruskal will be  `O(E α(E))`

And if sorting complexity is `O(nloglogn)`  the complexity of kruskal will be  `O(EloglogE)` and for dense graph it will be `O(v^2loglogv)` (`v` is number of vertices)